# How to get a callback on MongoDB collection.find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

When I run `collection.find()` in MongoDB/Node/Express, I'd like to get a callback when it's finished. What's the correct syntax for this?

```
 function (id,callback) {

    var o_id = new BSON.ObjectID(id);

    db.open(function(err,db){
      db.collection('users',function(err,collection){
        collection.find({'_id':o_id},function(err,results){  //What's the correct callback synatax here?
          db.close();
          callback(results);
        }) //find
      }) //collection
    }); //open
  }
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

That's the correct callback syntax, but what `find` provides to the callback is a [`Cursor`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html), not an array of documents.  So if you want your callback to provide results as an array of documents, call [`toArray`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#toArray) on the cursor to return them:

```
collection.find({'_id':o_id}, function(err, cursor){
    cursor.toArray(callback);
    db.close();
});
```

Note that your function's callback still needs to provide an `err` parameter so that the caller knows whether the query worked or not.

**2.x Driver Update**

`find` now returns the cursor rather than providing it via a callback, so the typical usage can be simplified to:

```
collection.find({'_id': o_id}).toArray(function(err, results) {...});
```

Or in this case where a single document is expected, it's simpler to use [`findOne`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOne):

```
collection.findOne({'_id': o_id}, function(err, result) {...});
```

Comment: So in this case where I'm only returning one result, it's normal to reference `data[0]` in the controller?

Comment: In that case you'd want to use `findOne` instead, which directly provides the document to the callback.  See http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findone

Answer (score 22):

Based on JohnnyHK answer I simply wrapped my calls inside db.open() method and it worked. Thanks @JohnnyHK.

```
app.get('/answers', function (req, res){
     db.open(function(err,db){ // <------everything wrapped inside this function
         db.collection('answer', function(err, collection) {
             collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
                 console.log(items);
                 res.send(items);
             });
         });
     });
});
```

Hope it is helpful as an example.

Comment: *And they call it... callback hell! It begins...*

Comment: I am using same but I got db.open is not function error can you help me