# Postman converts Mongo arrays to Objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object, postman

I am working on an application that uses MongoDB for data persistence, alongside the mongoose library to allow angularjs to communicate with it. I'm using Postman to test my routes, and that's where the problem comes in.

In MongoDB, I inserted an entry thusly:

```
db.posts.insert{{id:6, author:"Blah", area:"Sport", body:"bleh", user_id:6, comments:[{author:"foo", body:"bar"}]})
```

I then queried it through Postman, and it successfully returned the Post, but there was a problem. The comments array had been returned as a strange data type, object Object, and I could not access it from my HTML files.

This is what Postman retrieved:

```
{"_id":"5536112cffc7bf00b2585d24","id":6,"author":"Blah","area":"Sport","body":"bleh","user_id":6,"comments":["[object Object]"]}]
```

I want to be able to access the **author** and **body** elements of comments independently, or else to be able to get at them from my http files. Does anyone know how I might stop this Object-ification from happening, or failing that, how I might query the data from this new Object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing complete db object we can pass required parameters. below is the example to form the required parameters.

res.json({"author":item.author,"body":item.body});

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661545/how-to-get-a-callback-on-mongodb-collection-find) You can find call back function and array conversion from the cursor