# NodeJS Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Was previously directed to [How to get a callback on MongoDB collection.find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661545/how-to-get-a-callback-on-mongodb-collection-find) but this did not solve the problem.

This is from the nodeblog assignment of build 10 projects with nodejs. Had previously downloaded the instructors code and got the error. Later, wrapped everything in .toArray but am still receiving the same error.

```
TypeError: /Users/Dropbox/projects/nodeblog/views/addpost.jade:16
    14|             label Category
    15|             select.form-control(name='category')
  > 16|                 each category, i in categories
    17|                     option(value='#{category.title}') #{category.title}

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Here is the addpost.jade file

```
extends layout
block content
    h1=title
        .form-group
            label Title:
            input.form-control(name='title', type='text')
        .form-group
            label Category
            select.form-control(name='category')
                each category, i in categories
                    option(value='#{category.title}') #{category.title}
```

Here is the posts.js file

```
router.get('/add', function(req, res, next){
    var categories = db.get('categories');

    categories.find({},{}, function(err, categories){
        categories.toArray(function(err, catArray){
            res.render('addpost',{
                "title": "Add Post",
                "categories": categories
            });
    });
});
});

router.post('/add', function(req, res, next){
    // Get Form Values
    var title       = req.body.title;
    var category    = req.body.category;
    var body        = req.body.body;
    var author      = req.body.author;
    var date        = new Date();


    // Form Validation
    req.checkBody('title','Title field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('body', 'Body field is required');

    // Check Errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        res.render('addpost',{
            "errors": errors,
            "title": title,
            "body": body
        });
    } else {
        var posts = db.get('posts');

        // Submit to DB
        posts.insert({
            "title": title,
            "body": body,
            "category": category,
            "date": date,
            "author": author,
            "mainimage": mainImageName
        }, function(err, post){
            if(err){
                res.send('There was an issue submitting the post');
            } else {
                req.flash('success','Post Submitted');
                res.location('/');
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: mscdex, I took a look at the link, but not sure how that applies to my question? Are you saying that I have a error in syntax? I'm new so I may need a little more hand holding...

Comment: As indicated in the duplicate, the problem is that your callback in `categories.find` has a Cursor object, which does not have a `length` property. It seems you expect `categories` to be an array with a `length`, but it is not. Instead, you need to do `collections.toArray(function(err, collArray) { res.render(...) })` as indicated in the duplicate.

Comment: aspillers, can you show me what the syntax would look like? Is the categories.find you are mentioning the "i in categories"? or is it the category.title

Comment: The `categories.find` I mean is the only `categories.find` in the code you're provided. The full code inside the `categories.find` callback would be `categories.toArray(function(err, catArray) { res.render('addpost',{ "title": "Add Post", "categories": catArray }); })` -- just wrap your `res.render` call inside a callback to `categories.toArray`. (I previously mistyped "`categories`" as "`collections`", sorry.)

Comment: I wrapped everything in the toArray callback, but get the same error as before

Comment: Okay, great! Sounds like you're having a different problem after all. if you [edit] your question to show your new code (and add a link to the [current duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661545/how-to-get-a-callback-on-mongodb-collection-find) to explain that that question didn't solve your problem), I'd be happy to reopen your question.

Comment: Thanks apsillers, updated

Comment: Whoops, I thought I could open it by myself, but I can't. (I can reopen questions tagged `[javascript]` by myself, but this question doesn't have that tag.) I've voted to reopen, and it will probably be reopened soon once it gets 2 more reopen votes.