# Understanding find in Node/Mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to learn node.
Consider this code (based on official MongoDB Node.js driver)

```
  // Retrieve all the documents in the collection
  collection.find().toArray(function(err, documents) {
    assert.equal(1, documents.length);
    assert.deepEqual([1, 2, 3], documents[0].b);

    db.close();
  });
```

I have two questions:

- is `find` synchronous or asynchronous?
- If it is asynchronous, the `.toArray` function call is confusing me, because normally I would expect something along the lines of

  ```
  collection.find(function(err, results){});
  ```

Specifically I am interested **what mechanism** allows you to call a `.toArray` on **result of asynchronous function**? Because asynchronous functions as I get it rarely return something (I think except promises), rather invoke callbacks passed to them. Can someone clarify this situation with find and `.toArray`?

---

For example in the accepted answer of this question: [How to get a callback on MongoDB collection.find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661545/how-to-get-a-callback-on-mongodb-collection-find), you can see author calls `find` the way I envisioned, and received `cursor` in callback function. That is fine with me, that is how I expected it to work.
But **chaining** result of asynchronous call `find` (if it is asynch?), with `toArray` a bit confuses me.

My speculation is `find` returns a handle kind of thing, the data at this point hasn't been loaded from DB, only when you call `toArray` the actual data arrives. Am I right?

Comment: Could it be that this confusion comes from an API change? `find` in v2.2 returns a `Cursor` that comes with various methods (`toArray` being one of them). In v1.4 `find` accepts a number of arguments, one of them being an optional `callback` (while still returning a `cursor`).

Comment: @forrert yep, that was also factor in confusion. So in 2.2 find returns cursor object synchronously?

Comment: As the answer below points out nicely, in both cases a cursor is returned synchronously. Keep in mind, that a function that runs something asynchronously can still return something (e.g. the cursor). Also the cursor functions expect callbacks to receive the results of the query.

Answer (score 5):

I concede you, this case is a bit weird. Here is for the v2.2 of mongodb-native.

First of all, `find` has [two different usages](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/V2.2.24/lib/collection.js#L374). You can either give a callback function or not. But in **any case**, it returns **synchronously** an object. More precisely it's a [cursor](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/V2.2.24/lib/cursor.js#L100).
We could expect a asynchronous mechanism when passing a callback but not here.

```
collection.find({ }, function (err, cursor) {
  assert(!err);
});
console.log('This happens after collection.find({ }, callback)');
```

**OR**

```
const cursor = collection.find({});
console.log('Also happening after');
```

On the other hand, `toArray` is an asynchronous function and has also two different usages. This time, the returned object is different depending on the arguments.

Are equivalent:

```
cursor.toArray(function (err, documents) {
  assert.equal(1, documents.length);
});
```

**AND**

```
cursor.toArray()
  .then(documents => {
    assert.equal(1, documents.length);
  });
```

In the first call, `toArray` returns `undefined` whereas in the second, it returns a `Promise`.