# Issue with Javascript foreach Async behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, foreach

After a bit of research online, it seems like Javascirpt's forEach loop IS blocking but my following code is proving otherwise:

I am using node js mongoDB driver to get docs from my collection which is an array (named documents)

```
 collectionInstance.find({}, function(err, documents) {
      if (err || !documents) {
        console.log('no documents found in the collection');
      } else {

        console.log('before');

        documents.forEach(function(document) {
          console.log('inside')
        });

        console.log('outside');


      }
    });
```

What I want:

```
before -> inside, inside, inside .... inside -> outside
```

What it's giving me:

```
before -> outside -> inside, inside, inside .... inside
```

Why is the loop behaving as if it's non blocking?

Comment: is `documents` just a regular javascript Array? or is it something more exotic?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11661778/1623249. `documents` may actually be a `cursor`, not an array

Comment: If this is actually the native driver and not mongoose then you get your expected behavior by `.find().toArray(err,documents)`. After `.toArray()` returns a regular array, then you have a plain JavaScript `.forEach()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript's `Array.prototype.forEach` is synchronous ("blocking"), yes. But Mongo's `Collection.find` returns a [`Cursor`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html) whose `.forEach` method is asynchronous and callback based. `Cursor.forEach` accepts a *second* callback which is called once you've iterated over all results:

```
documents.forEach(function (document) {
  console.log('inside');
}, function () {
  console.log('outside');
});
```