# Unable to mutate Array in node JS mongo db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, mongodb-query

I am using rest API of node with mongodb and I am getting some error like

I am unable to mutate array arr when it's push in that response function.
every time I got an empty array in it.

What im using:

```
              var arr = [];
                Business.find({ userId: userId }, (err,docss)=>{
                    if(err) throw err;
                    arr.push(docss)
                });
               console.warn(arr)
```

OUTPUT : []

thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a callback on MongoDB collection.find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661545/how-to-get-a-callback-on-mongodb-collection-find)

Comment: You get [] output because of Event Loop (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). You call async Business.find method but callback with arr.push will be fired after console.warn.

Comment: I got this error @RandyCasburn :TypeError: cursor.toArray is not a function,                    and here's my code  Business.find({ userId: userId}, function (err, cursor) {
               var m = cursor.toArray();
               console.warn(m)
            });